# Hibernate prevents me from logging in into a read-only Postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I replicated one of my databases on AWS. It's an RDS instance. After that, all I did was change the endpoint in my pom file in my application to point to the new read replica. However, when I run the code locally via intelliJ and get to the log in page, logging in produces the following error:

```
Hibernate: select authorizat0_.id as id1_0_2_, authorizat0_.expirationDate as expirati2_0_2_, authorizat0_.timeCreated as timeCrea3_0_2_, authorizat0_.token as token4_0_2_, authorizat0_.user_id as user_id5_0_2_, user1_.id as id1_6_0_, user1_.timeCreated as timeCrea2_6_0_, user1_.uuid as uuid3_6_0_, user1_.version as version4_6_0_, user1_.company_id as company_5_6_0_, user1_.emailAddress as emailAdd6_6_0_, user1_.firstName as firstNam7_6_0_, user1_.hashedPassword as hashedPa8_6_0_, user1_.isVerified as isVerifi9_6_0_, user1_.lastName as lastNam10_6_0_, user1_.phoneNumber as phoneNu11_6_0_, user1_.role as role12_6_0_, user1_.signatureImage as signatu13_6_0_, company2_.id as id1_1_1_, company2_.timeCreated as timeCrea2_1_1_, company2_.uuid as uuid3_1_1_, company2_.version as version4_1_1_, company2_.accountId as accountI5_1_1_, company2_.additional_setting as addition6_1_1_, company2_.beginningDate as beginnin7_1_1_, company2_.city as city8_1_1_, company2_.country as country9_1_1_, company2_.expirationDate as expirat12_1_1_, company2_.logo as logo25_1_1_, company2_.logoType as logoTyp26_1_1_, company2_.name as name27_1_1_, company2_.need_disclaimer as need_di28_1_1_, company2_.state as state30_1_1_, company2_.statement as stateme31_1_1_, company2_.streetAddress1 as streetA32_1_1_, company2_.streetAddress2 as streetA33_1_1_,  company2_.use_customer_supplier_id as use_cus35_1_1_,  company2_.user_id as user_id37_1_1_, company2_.zipcode as zipcode38_1_1_ from authorization_token authorizat0_ left outer join "user" user1_ on authorizat0_.user_id=user1_.id left outer join company company2_ on user1_.company_id=company2_.id where authorizat0_.user_id=?
    Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
    09:44:19.651 [qtp951562287-24] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: cannot execute nextval() in a read-only transaction
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Does hibernate need to be configured differently when using a read-only database? This application works fine with any write databases by simply changing my endpoint to one

Comment: What is the `ddl-auto` value?

Comment: @TonyYip are you talking about this from the persistence.xml file?   
          `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is trying to write some data through an INSERT statement for which it tries to acquire a sequence value and fails because the database is read-only. You will have to adapt the application to not do any writes on this database.